# Nested filter throws error but can't understand why

Tags: powerbi, dax, measure

Below measure throws me an error, but can't understand why, or how I could solve the issue. If someone could explain it to me that'd be great !

```
CALCULATE (
  SUM(BASE_SALES[VOLUME]),
  FILTER(
    BASE_SALES,
    BASE_SALES[STORE] IN FILTER(STATES, STATES[STATE] = "Cleveland")
  )
)
```

error message (is French):

> Le nombre d'arguments n'est pas valide. La fonction CONTAINSROW doit avoir une valeur pour chaque colonne de l'expression de table.

Comment: you are trying to search ``BASE_SALES[STORE]`` which is one column in all ``STATES`` columns...

Comment: Thanks, do you know how I can search BASE_SALES[STORE] in column STATES[STORE] while having STATES table filtered (STATES[STATE] = "Cleveland") ?

Comment: Hi @Pauline, If you have a store column in your states table, then try this one:
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( BASE_SALES[VOLUME] ),
    FILTER (
        BASE_SALES,
        BASE_SALES[STORE]
            IN FILTER ( VALUES ( STATES[STORE] ), STATES[STATE] = "Cleveland" )
    )
)

Comment: @OzanSen this `FILTER ( VALUES ( STATES[STORE] ), STATES[STATE] = "Cleveland" )` wont work - FILTER is iterator there are no STATES in STATES[STORE]  column.

Comment: @Mik Yeah correctly! Maybe I expected DAX to perform miracles for me there. I am wrong!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the reason for error `BASE_SALES[STORE] IN FILTER(STATES, STATES[STATE] = "Cleveland")` - When you use IN it should be a list of Values not a table. For example:

```
BASE_SALES[STORE] IN CALCULATETABLE(VALUES(STATES[STORE]), STATES[STATE] = "Cleveland")
```

I'm not sure about your aim but try this if tables are linked

```
CALCULATE (
  SUM(BASE_SALES[VOLUME])
  ,STATES[STATE] = "Cleveland"
)
```

If they are not linked then try this :

```
CALCULATE (
  SUM(BASE_SALES[VOLUME])
  ,TREATAS(
     CALCULATETABLE(VALUES(STATES[STORE]),STATES[STATE] = "Cleveland")
     ,BASE_SALES[STORE]
  )
)
```

Comment: They are linked but inactively, so should work like below right ? (No more errors at least, so thank you !!)
CALCULATE (
  SUM(BASE_SALES[VOLUME]),
  STATES[STATE] = "Cleveland",
  USERELATIONSHIP(BASE_SALES[STORE], STATES[STORE])
)

Comment: right, yes it should

Comment: I added some explanation it also should be useful

Comment: Thanks, real useful, seems simple but couldn't get the hang of it !